# using clang-tidy to findout all uncaught exceptions

Tags: c++, uncaught-exception, clang-tidy

I want to use clang-tidy to find out all uncaught exceptions by its direct or indirect caller, up to main, but this demo has no effect. Generally, I want to clang-tidy to report that the function cc is throwing an exception that not being caught by main, but it reports nothing, I want to know why & how can I achieve my goal? Thks

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int m = 0;
extern int cc() throw();

int ff() {
  if (m > 0) {
    throw "H";
  }
  return 1;
}

int gg() {
  if (m > 0) {
    return ff();
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}


int main() {
  return cc();
}
```

`cc.cpp`

```cpp
extern int m;
int cc() {
  if (m > 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  throw "D";
}
```

`.clang-tidy`

```json
Checks: '-*,bugprone-exception-escape' 
CheckOptions: 
    - key: FunctionsThatShouldNotThrow
      value: main
HeaderFilterRegex: '.*'
```

`command`

```sh
clang-tidy main.cpp cc.cpp
```

Comment: `int cc() throw();` (or `noexcept` in more recent version), so exception of `cc` doesn"t escape to `main`. As `throw "D";` is uncaught, it would call [`std::unexpected()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected).

Answer (score 0):

1. it turns out that clang-tidy can not detect cross file checks. If I concatenate the two cpp files, clang-tidy can identify the uncaught exception successfully.
2. the configuration file for clang-tidy is wrong, the `key` in `CheckOptions` should be `bugprone-exception-escape.FunctionsThatShouldNotThrow` instead of `FunctionsThatShouldNotThrow`